# DBMS_LOB.LoadFromFile Sanity Check

Tags: oracle, plsql, blob

I think that maybe I am starting to get the process here, but it is so odd that I doubt myself.  In the following, see the comments for what the point of confusions are.

```
DECLARE
    srcFile   BFILE := BFILENAME('SOME_DIR', 'xyz.pdf');
    fLen      NUMBER;
    dest      BLOB;

  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO SomeTable
    VALUES ( 1, 'xyz.pdf',  EMPTY_BLOB(), null ) -- Does this establish an active ref.?
    RETURNING pdf_file INTO dest;

    DBMS_LOB.OPEN(srcFile, dbms_lob.file_readonly);
    fLen := dbms_lob.getlength(srcFile);

    DBMS_LOB.LOADFROMFILE(dest, srcFile, fLen); -- Does this reach into the table row,
                                                -- and fill it with the file’s contents?
    dbms_lob.close(srcFile);
    commit;
  END;
```

And is the following the way to update the BLOB in a row that already exists?

```
DECLARE
    srcFile   BFILE := BFILENAME('SOME_DIR', 'xyz.pdf');
    fLen      NUMBER;
    dest      BLOB;

  BEGIN
    SELECT pdf_file INTO dest -- Does this est. an active reference?
    FROM SomeTable   
    WHERE ID = 1; -- ( <———<<< ' = 1' is just for example.)

    DBMS_LOB.OPEN(srcFile, dbms_lob.file_readonly);
    fLen := dbms_lob.getlength(srcFile);

    DBMS_LOB.LoadFromFile(dest, srcFile, fLen); -- Does this reach into the row,
                                                -- filling it w/ the file’s contents?
    dbms_lob.close(srcFile);
    commit;
  END;
```

This seems a lot more like .NET's handling of database adapters, and the FileInfo, DirInfo functions.  But I haven't seen that kind of philosophy in Oracle anywhere else.

I would have expected

```
  BLOBVariable = LoadFromFile(srcLocator, byteCnt); -- where the func. rtrns a val,
```

fol’d by

```
  INSERT INTO SomeTable (pdf_file)
  VALUES              (BLOBVariable);
```

Am I seeing this right?
If so, when is the reference abandoned?
I seem to recall reading that 'commit' is not necessary when using 'LoadFromFile?'

And now, this morning I see an example (with no explanation) that selects the BLOB field into a variable, using FOR UPDATE to lock the record.  Might be good to understand what's up with that...

```
    -- Lock the record
    execute immediate 'SELECT pdf_file INTO dest
                       FROM   image_blobs
                       WHERE  itl_image_blob_id = :1
                       FOR UPDATE' 
    INTO v_blob_data
    using < the row identifier goes here >;

    -- Read the file
    dbms_lob.loadfromfile(dests, srcFile, fLen);

    -- update the blob field
    execute immediate '
        UPDATE image_blobs
        SET    pdf_file = :1
        WHERE  itl_image_blob_id = :2' 
    using dest, < row identifier >;
```

Comment: I meant to say --- BLOBVariable = LoadFromFile(srcLocator, byteCount), followed by INSERT INTO SomeTable (pdf_file) VALUES (BLOBVariable);

Answer (score 1):

The following showed me that my sanity is intact, and that the INSERT statement really does create a reference that `loadfromfile()` uses.  This answer with respect to an INSERT statement is good enough for my purposes, so I am going to assume that the UPDATE functionality is similar.  `'IMPORT_DIR'` is a named database directory in the database.

```
DROP TABLE TEST_BLOBS purge; -- 'purge' prevents loading up the recycle bin.
CREATE TABLE TEST_BLOBS (
  ID            VARCHAR(4),
  F_NAME        VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  CONTENT_TYPE  VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  F_SIZE        NUMBER(10),
  BLOB_DATA     BLOB DEFAULT empty_blob() );

DECLARE
    dest    blob;                 tmp_id  varchar2(4);
    v_f_sz  NUMBER(10);           b_file  BFILE := NULL;
    fName   VARCHAR2 (50);

    CURSOR get_items IS SELECT filename FROM My_Table_of_names;
BEGIN
  FOR a_rec IN get_items LOOP
    fName  := a_rec.filename;
    b_file := BFILENAME ( 'IMPORT_DIR', fName );
    IF DBMS_LOB.fileexists (b_file) = 0 THEN  
      -- Report the problem and exit.
    END IF;

    DBMS_LOB.fileopen ( b_file, DBMS_LOB.file_readonly );
    v_f_sz := DBMS_LOB.getlength (b_file);

    INSERT INTO test_blobs (            ID,   content_type,   f_name, f_size,   blob_data      )
    VALUES                 ( <Some_ID_val>, 'application/pdf',  fName,  v_f_sz, empty_blob()   )
    RETURNING blob_data, ID   INTO dest, tmp_id;

    -- Table field contains data, (HUGEBLOB),
    -- when debugging and loop ends here.

    DBMS_LOB.loadfromfile(dest, b_file, v_f_sz);
    DBMS_LOB.close(b_file);

    -- After running this, the variable tmp_id has the value that was assigned in the INSERT statement,
    -- and the table’s fields, 'BLOB_Data', have the contents of the files.   dest is indeed a reference
    -- to the row and field, allowing LoadFromFile() to put data into the table.
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```